# Construct LINQ query using variables in asp.net WebAPI

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to build a method in my asp.net WebAPI to grab data based on the arguments passed on the method. The method is used to perform a search on restaurant data. I have a variable called 'type' that determines the type of data search performed. The second variable 'keyword' is the keyword searched by the user. The WHERE condition in my LINQ query depends on the type and needs to be dynamic, so I have used a separate variable outside the LINQ query to define the condition. I have tried assigning this variable to my WHERE statement on the LINQ query but it doesn't seem to work. Can someone help with it please? I have been stuck on this for a few days now

```
public IQueryable<RestaurantView> GetRestaurantsForSearch(string keyword, int type, string location)
    {
        //
        var condition = "";
        if(type == 1)
        {
           condition = "x.RestaurantName.Contains(keyword)";
        } else if(type == 2){
            condition = "x.Cuisine.Equals(keyword)"; 
        }
        else {
            condition = "x.Rating.Equals(keyword)";
        }

        var query = from x in db.Restaurants
                    join y in db.Cuisine on x.RestaurantCuisine equals y.CuisineID
                    where condition
                    select new RestaurantView
                    {
                        RestaurantID = x.RestaurantID,
                        RestaurantName = x.RestaurantName,
                        RestaurantCuisine = y.CuisineName,
                        RestaurantDecription = x.RestaurantDecription
                    };


        return query;
    }
```

Comment: Please read on Expression (i.e. start from links in [Queryable.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040.aspx) and update you question to something like "how to build Expression to compare single property for LINQ to SQL".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look a dynamic linq library i think then you can execute string statements inside your linq

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

or you can execute direct query

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executequery.aspx

Comment: Dynamic Linq is the way to go.  I use in my app to construct completely dynamic queries and it really cut down on the coding.  You can create a where condition from the string like `.Where(String.Format("RestaurantName.Contains({0})", keyword))`.

Comment: Thanks @COLD TOLD, Dynamic Linq is surely the way to go! Worked for me perfectly!

Comment: This reminds me too much of manually building queries with strings which defeats the purpose of LINQ IMO. The predicate builder or Chris Hardies answer feels cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Predicate<Restaurant> pred;
if (type == 1) pred = x => x.RestaurantName.Contains(keyword);
else if (type == 2) pred = x => x.Cuisine.Equals(keyword);
else pred = x => x.Rating.Equals(keyword);

var query = from x in db.Restaurants
            join y in db.Cuisine on x.RestaurantCuisine equals y.CuisineID
            where pred(x)

            select new RestaurantView
            {
                RestaurantID = x.RestaurantID,
                RestaurantName = x.RestaurantName,
                RestaurantCuisine = y.CuisineName,
                RestaurantDecription = x.RestaurantDecription
            };
return query;
```

Comment: This is another way of altering how your expression tree gets built out. I prefer doing it this way or with my answer over dynamic LINQ because I appreciate keeping things strongly-typed.

Comment: Thanks @CSJ. I tried using your method but I get the following exception                                                         `The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.","ExceptionType":"System.NotSupportedException","StackTrace":"   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.NotSupportedTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)\r\n   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)`

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with dropping your comprehensive LINQ query in favour of the extension method syntax, it's pretty simple (I'm on a netbook without VS, so I apologize that this is untested but should give you the idea):

```
var query = db.Restaurants
            .Include("Cuisine")

if(type == 1)
{
    query= query.Where(x => x.RestaurantName.Contains(keyword));
} 
else if(type == 2)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Cuisine == keyword); 
}
else {
    query = query.Where(x => x.Rating == keyword);
}
```

This builds out your expression tree differently based on your logic checks, which will result in a different SQL query being generated based on the value of `type`.

I notice that in your join, `Cuisine` appears to be an Entity, but in your logic checks, you attempt to filter by comparing `Cuisine` to a string so I think there is some disconnect.

Comment: Thanks @Chris Hardie, I ended up using Dynamic Linq but your answer is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
                  var query = from x in db.Restaurants
                join y in db.Cuisine on x.RestaurantCuisine equals  y.CuisineID
                where condition
                select new RestaurantView
                {
                    RestaurantID = x.RestaurantID,
                    RestaurantName = x.RestaurantName,
                    RestaurantCuisine = y.CuisineName,
                    RestaurantDecription = x.RestaurantDecription
                };


    return query;
}
```

how to get the  return query value in client side to assign for grid view binding